# Problemas de Rutas Laravel con parámetros desde href

Tags: jquery, laravel

Tengo un problema. Ante todo perdonad si digo alguna obviedad, pero soy novato.

Tengo un proyecto Laravel 8. Intento que a través de un `"<a>"` pasar la ruta para que el controlador haga una consulta a la base de datos y lance una vista blade.

Mi fichero web.php:

```php
 Route::get('prueba/{inicio}/{final}', 'App\Http\Controllers\SalidaController@prueba')->name('prueba');
```

Mi función de jQuery para poner el `"<a>"`:

```javascript
function footerReportResponse(tipo, fecini, fecfin) {
  footer = '<a class="btn btn-info linkVer" data-inicio="' + fecini + '" data-final="' + fecfin + '">Ver Salidas</a>';
  $('.modal-footer').html(footer);
}
```

Mi función del controlador:

```php
public function prueba($inicio, $final) { 
    $user = Auth::user(); 
    $salidas = DB::table('salidas') 
        ->where([ 
            ['users_id', '=', $user->id],
            ['fecha', '>=', $inicio],
            ['fecha', '<=', $final], 
        ]) 
        ->get();
    return view('salida.indexSalidas', compact('salida'); 
}
```

Comment: Debes poner texto en lugar de imagenes cuando quieras mostrarnos código. Aparte de eso, no especificas el error que tienes, solo dices que tienes un problema, pero no cual es.   Estaria bien que nos lo dijeras para que no tuvieramos que adivinarlo.

Comment: Si perdonar, he sido un poquito rápido. el error que me da es "403 forbbiden"

Comment: Por favor, edita tu publicacion para poder replicar lo que has hecho y ayudarte con un solucion.

Comment: Fichero web: 
Route::get('prueba/{inicio}/{final}', 'App\Http\Controllers\SalidaController@prueba')->name('prueba');

Comment: Fichero jquery:       function footerReportResponse(tipo,fecini,fecfin) {
             footer = '<a class="btn btn-info linkVer" data-inicio="'+fecini+'" data-final="'+fecfin+'">Ver Salidas</a>';
             $('.modal-footer').html(footer);
      }

Comment: función controlador:     public function prueba($inicio, $final) {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $salidas = DB::table('salidas')
                    ->where([
                        ['users_id', '=', $user->id],
                        ['fecha', '>=', $inicio],
                        ['fecha', '<=', $final],
                    ])
                    ->get();
        return view('salida.indexSalidas', compact('salida');  
    }

Comment: Borra tus comentarios con el código, acabo de ponerlo en la pregunta

Comment: El error 403 es una respuesta del servidor web, por lo tanto lo mejor seria que revisaras como queda el `href=` despues de todo ese código, y verifica tu mismo si es correcto o apunta a alguna cosa rara.  Para ello tan solo debes inspeccionar el footer en el html de salida con tu navegador (boton derecho, Inspeccionar) y ver lo que pone.

Comment: La url que yo pongo es: "$('.modal-footer').on('click', '.linkVer', function(){
       var fecini = $(this).data('inicio'),
        fecfin = $(this).data('final');
       
       var ruta = '{{route(\'prueba\', [\'$inicio\'=>'+fecini+', \'$final\'=>'+fecfin+'])}}'; 
       $('.linkVer').attr('href',ruta);"  Y la que sale es: "http://localhost:8383/entrenamiento/public/%7B%7Broute('prueba',%20['$inicio'=%3E2022-01-01,%20'$final'=%3E2022-01-18])%7D%7D"

Comment: He intentado usar la función codeURIComponent (en las llaves), pero me da el mismo resultado.

Comment: No se apenas nada de laravel, pero esa ruta: `var ruta = '{{route(\'prueba\', [\'$inicio\'=>'+fecini+', \'$final\'=>'+fecfin+'])}}'; ` no parece resuelta por Laravel, sino que la deja tal cual... ¿Quizas es que la has puesto en un archivo javascript directamente sin interpretarse antes por Laravel?  Ya te digo, no se Laravel, que conste, pero no parece que pase por alli para interpretar nada.

Comment: la cargo en el html desde javaScript, y es el formato de Laravel para incluir una ruta en un href. El problema creo que va por el tema de los símbolos ({, ? y &), he utilizado la función "decodeURIComponent" de javaScript para que los traduzca correctamente, y no aparezcan en la url como "%20 o %F7, etc..."

Comment: Al final lo que voy a hacer es recuperar la información por una función Ajax con json y generar la tabla directamente con javaScript en el html. Muchas gracias

Comment: No estoy muy seguro que eso funcione asi... es decir, que sea practico crear urls con los código propios de Laravel como eso del `{{route`, etc... diria que tienes un problema de concepto en este caso, no tiene sentido la verdad.  ¿Tu has visto alguna vez una web con esos códigos en sus urls?

Comment: Si, puede que tengas razón, ya comenté que soy novato. He visto este tipo de href: "<li><a href="{{ route('usuarios.index')}}">Usuarios</a></li>" por ejemplo, pero se supone que laravel admite rutas con parámetros también, de hecho está en la documentación. Por eso intentaba hacerlo de esta forma. De todas formas, gracias por tu aportación.

Comment: Seguramente has visto eso en algun archivo php o html o plantilla que Laravel va a interpretar y modificar poniendo una URL válida correspondiente a ese route, pero no en el javascript que estas usando, de ahi que no funcione supongo.